# Assign char to char *

Tags: c, arrays, string

I need an entire string to be one char of another string.

```
const char *const_string = "FOOBAR";
char *character_string = malloc(1024);
// character_string = const_string[3];
```

How can I make the last (commented) line work?

Comment: It is not clear what result you want to get.

Comment: change int val to char val

Comment: @VladfromMoscow set `str` to "s".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you mean the following

```
void do_something(char *str, int idx)
{
    str[0] = glob_str[idx];
    str[1] = '\0';
}
```

You can add a check to the function that the index is not outside the string literal pointed to by `glob_str`.

Comment: @Redesign Vlad's code should work. Please post the entire program you are running which gives you just an empty string.

Comment: Oops, never mind. I had a leftover piece of code that was messing me up.

Comment: @Redesign If your problem is resolved, please do one of (1) accept Vlad's answer (2) delete your question (3) write some kind of note at the top of your question. This is so that we know it's solved and people don't have to spend time reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
char *glob_str = "test test";  // glob_str is literal string and cannot be modified
```

then

```
glob_str[0] = val; // modification won't work
```

You need to change to

```
char glob_str[] = "test test";
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Comment: You're not wrong, but I don't think that is wht OP is trying to do. I think he wants to set his malloc'd buffer to just { glob_str[0], '\0', ... }